# Масштабирование imageView android при фокусе на edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-imageview, focus

У меня в приложении есть два edittext, кнопка и imageview, так вот нужно сделать так что-бы при фокусе на первом edittext у меня картинка в imageview масштабировалась и перемещалась к верху экрана. То есть при фокусе первом edittext у меня imageview должно уменьшаться и переползать наверх. Я пробую такой код:

```
final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
final ImageView lock = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

titleEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                    lock.getLayoutParams().width = 140;
                    lock.getLayoutParams().height = 50;

                }
            }
        });
```

Но у меня почему-то после фокуса не меняется размер, может его как-то нужно применить? И падинги куда нужно ставить, а то не очень понятно как применять новые параметры. Если кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой то буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: ставите листенер на editeText. Внутрь листенера помещаете анимацию, изменение размеров и падингов картинки. Пожалуйста, перечитайте, что вы нам написали))

Comment: вроде перечитал, но не уверен что исправил то что вы имели в виду, может я что-то не заметил?))

Comment: напротив) после редактирования вопрос стал очень даже)